How to set the minimal height of the rectangles in D3's zoomable icicle
In my React app I would like to add this kind of zoomable icicle and use my own data for it: https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-icicle
The problem I came across was that some of my data was having too big differences in the values which made some of the rectangles become invisible or just too small to even target and click on them for zooming.
My initial thought was to try and add a minimal height to the rectangles and adjust the rest of them with the remaining space but this proved to be too big of a challenge, especially due to the fact I've never worked with D3 before.
Can anyone share some pointers on how to fix this or think of any different ideas?
